# using #define macro in okta

Tags: okta, okta-api

I use ngrok to test my flask app with OKTA. For which my ngrok public URL gets changed time to time. I need to change my OKTA application integration setting based on the current URL as given below

```
Single Sign On URL  http://4e4f-103-97-210-83.ngrok.io/saml/sso/example-okta-com

Recipient URL  http://4e4f-103-97-210-83.ngrok.io/saml/sso/example-okta-com

Destination URL http://4e4f-103-97-210-83.ngrok.io/saml/sso/example-okta-comAudience 

Restriction  http://4e4f-103-97-210-83.ngrok.io/saml/sso/example-okta-com
```

it is very tedious jobs to change URL everywhere when there is only change in string "4e4f-103-97-210-83"

is there any macro facility to define in OKTA app integration something like below

```
# url_part    4e4f-103-97-210-83
http://${url_part}.ngrok.io/saml/sso/example-okta-com
```

I just need to change url_part macro based on ngrok output, and it is good to go.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Okta API to make this change for your app config, or Terraform which uses the same under the hood.

Or you can get a plan from ngrok, which allows to keep public URL permanent

Comment: anything other than ngrok, which can provide me permanent ip at free cost?

Comment: sorry, not sure what to recommend :( try to google around